# encrypt file in php with Mcrypt

Tags: php, encryption

I use this code for encrypt file in php:

```
<?php
// The password
$passphrase = 'My secret';

// Turn a human readable passphrase
// into a reproducible iv/key pair

$iv = substr(md5("\x1B\x3C\x58".$passphrase, true), 0, 8);
$key = substr(md5("\x2D\xFC\xD8".$passphrase, true) .
md5("\x2D\xFC\xD9".$passphrase, true), 0, 24);
$opts = array('iv' => $iv, 'key' => $key, 'mode' => 'stream');

// Open the file
$fp = fopen('panel.css', 'wb');

// Add the Mcrypt stream filter
// We use Triple DES here, but you
// can use other encryption algorithm here
stream_filter_append($fp, 'mcrypt.tripledes', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts);

// Wrote some contents to the file
fwrite($fp, 'Secret secret secret data');

// Close the file
fclose($fp);
```

but when run above code this error happen:

```
stream_filter_append(): Could not open encryption module
```

I check for mcrypt extension with this code:

```
if (extension_loaded('mcrypt') === true)
    {
        echo "Mcrypt exist !";
    }
```

and Mcrypt exist ! displayed.also I check php.ini for Mcrypt and this line is about Mcrypt:

```
[mcrypt]
; For more information about mcrypt settings see http://php.net/mcrypt-module-open

; Directory where to load mcrypt algorithms
; Default: Compiled in into libmcrypt (usually /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt)
;mcrypt.algorithms_dir=

; Directory where to load mcrypt modes
; Default: Compiled in into libmcrypt (usually /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt)
;mcrypt.modes_dir=
```

any one can help me ?

Comment: I check /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt directory and that directory is empty